# Cannot access embedded resource with en-US.resx extension

Tags: c#, resources, globalization

I have a C# .NET 4.5 project with a custom embeded resource file Messages.en-US.resx

And I cannot access it using this

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;

MyApp.Properties.Resources.Messages.MyString
```

If I add a new resource file without .en-US.resx extension then it works....but I need it for translation to different languages

In my other ASP.NET projects works fine, in Winforms not.
I need this resource file for translation.

Comment: Have you checked your references? Have you specified the complete path? (i.e. <ns1>.<ns2>. ... .<class>)

Comment: I have using System.Reflection and System.Resources

Comment: My resource does not appear in any path

Comment: Your resource designer generated file must have a namespace.

Comment: CustomToolNamespace ?

Comment: Usually, the way you get to a resource, is: <ProjectName>.<ResourceFileNameWithoutLanguageSpecs>.<ResourceName>

Comment: The namespace is the Messages name from messages.en-us.resx but I cannot find it in intellisense

Comment: What is the project name? the one that contains the Messages.resx?

Comment: GFXMark.Properties.Resources.Messages.MyString does not exist

Comment: GFXMark is the project name

Comment: How about just GFXMark.Messages.MyString ?

Comment: No, it does not work.

Comment: other image resources works with Properties.Resources.myImage without any problem in the same project

Comment: Strange. Try to go the `.designer.cs` file of the resource file, and in there you will see the namespace, the name of the class, and the auto-generated memeber

Comment: The namespace is Messages

Comment: If I add a new resource file without .en-US. it works

Comment: Why it does not work with .en-US. ? because I need to add translations for different languages

Comment: Attempt to remove the ".en-US" part, recompile, and try again.

Comment: when I remove the .en-US part it works.

Comment: I think that the project should also have a normal resx file without the language extension.

Comment: I think your problem is that you need at least one file that has no language-specific extension for default resource (in case local environment culture is not found in your resources). That, I guess, the compiler compiles only the .designer file of the non-specific file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one messages resource file has to be non-culture-specific. That file has to have a matching `.designer` file.

Comment: yes one resource file need to be without the .language extension